# Formating (n)h (n)m (n)s into hh:mm:ss

Tags: google-sheets, time, formatting, google-sheets-formula, duration

I am trying to format a list of names with times into the format hh:ss:mm from (n)h (n)m (n)s[image]

If anyone knows how to do it that'd be so kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY(, "select  "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J2:J27, 
 "d", "*86400"), "h", "*3600"), "m", "*60"), "s", "*1"), " ", "+")))/86400, 2))
```